# C++ Why is the destructor immediately called after the object has been constructed in the stack?

Tags: c++, destructor, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have two unit tests. In the first one I create the object myMovie in the stack. The object is created and immediately afterwards the destructor is called. This causes the unit test to fail because when myMovie falls out of scope, the destructor is called again. This results in an access violation.

However, if I create the object in the Heap, everything works just fine. 
Why is the destructor immediately called after the object has been constructed in the stack?

First one like this:

```
TEST_METHOD(constructingMovieWithParametersStack)
    {
        _CrtMemState s1, s2, s3;
        _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s1);
        {
            Movie myMovie = Movie("firstName", "lastName", "title");
            // Why is the destructor is called here???

            string expectedDirectorFirst = "firstName";
            string expectedDirectorLast = "lastName";
            string expectedTitle = "title";
            wchar_t* message = L"movie title wasn't set correctly";
            Assert::AreEqual(expectedTitle, myMovie.getTitle(), message, LINE_INFO());
        }
        _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s2);
        wchar_t* leakMessage = L"there is a leak";
        bool isThereALeak = _CrtMemDifference(&s3, &s1, &s2);
        Assert::IsFalse(isThereALeak, leakMessage, LINE_INFO());
    }
```

Second unit test like this:

```
TEST_METHOD(constructingMovieWithParametersHeap)
    {
        _CrtMemState s1, s2, s3;
        _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s1);
        {
            Movie* myMovie = new Movie("firstName", "lastName", "title");

            string expectedDirectorFirst = "firstName";
            string expectedDirectorLast = "lastName";
            string expectedTitle = "title";
            wchar_t* message = L"movie title wasn't set correctly";
            Assert::AreEqual(expectedTitle, myMovie->getTitle(), message, LINE_INFO());
            delete myMovie;
        }
        _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s2);
        wchar_t* leakMessage = L"there is a leak";
        bool isThereALeak = _CrtMemDifference(&s3, &s1, &s2);
        Assert::IsFalse(isThereALeak, leakMessage, LINE_INFO());
    }
```

Here is the Movie class:

```
#include "Movie.h"

using namespace std;

Movie::Movie()
{
    this->director = new Person();
    this->title = "";
    this->mediaType = 'D';    // for DVD
}

Movie::Movie(string firstName, string lastName, string title)
{
    this->director = new Person();
    this->director->setFirstName(firstName);
    this->director->setLastName(lastName);
    this->title = title;
    this->mediaType = 'D';    // for DVD
}

Movie::~Movie()
{
    delete director;
}

string Movie::getTitle()
{
    return title;
}
```

Comment: @Leeor: Hi! Welcome to the _comment section_. It is for comments. You write comments when you want to request more information from the question author to help you answer the question. When you are ready to provide a solution to the problem, you write an _answer_. The answer section is down there: ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, dude, no reason for this tone. When I wrote the comment there was no answer yet, and I think questions about a fundamental concept could be answered by a simple "look up subject X" comment, especially since it must have been asked dozens of times already.

Comment: @Leeor: What "tone"? I went out of my way to be nice to you. There's just no pleasing some people. *sigh*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Movie myMovie = Movie("firstName", "lastName", "title");
// Why is the destructor is called here???
```

here a temporary object is created and used to copy initialize `myMovie`, then the temporary is destructed.

Did you mean

```
Movie myMovie("firstName", "lastName", "title");
```

Comment: and if the original code causes an access violation, that's a strong indicator of wildly broken copy semantics in `Movie`.